# Sync multiple local MongoDB databases to one remote database

Tags: database, mongodb, synchronization

In order to build a native desktop application with Electron that can be installed by users in many desktops. Every user must install a local MongoDB database to use the application locally. Now i want to provide a cloud service that can sync the local database for every registered user to the remote server MongoDB database. I'm thinking about putting every local database as a collection in the remote database or maybe just create all the local databases in the remote database by renaming their databases to their usernames.

Which method is good for me? is there a best practice for this problem? what about the limits?

Comment: I would suggest first approach making local db as collection in remote with some meta-data regarding users & how much data for that user so that it would help you for recovery and replication

Comment: This seems a good approach